# Как в python работать с html подобным образм как это реализовано в php?

Tags: php, html, python, веб-программирование

Раньше писал backend web приложений используя php, сейчас стоит задача разработать приложение для отправки html e-maill писем. Требуется работа с html похожим образом как это реализовано в php. Какую библиотеку стоит использовать?

Comment: Если для больших серьёзных проектов - Django. Если что попроще - Flask.

Comment: Не нужно работать как в php, он ужасен